# Programming  languages reccomended for a career in game design

Tags: software-engineering, career

I'm currently in year 11 and about to complete the highest level IT subject that my school offers leaving me no advanced programming courses to do next year. My question is: are there any quality online courses worth doing and which languages should i focus on learning. So far I've learnt java applet writing semi-self taught myself Android activity writing in Eclipse and tiny bits of c* and I pretty much know Gamemaker back to front.

So if i wanted to move into a career in programming for games, and such, which courses would you recommend, and which languages would you study?

Comment: What level are we talking about. If you can name your course and institution we can recommend something that fits neatly after.

Comment: Read the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq), your question is too broad and leads to discussion. You can make a game in any turing complete language, for that matter.

Comment: The language you use is completely irrelevant, at the level of competency required for game design you should be able to learn a new language in less than a month. What actually counts is knowledge that is attained by using pretty-much any language under the sun: things like data structures, OpenGL, DirectX, **having finished a game in whichever language you deem fit**. Most people would say C++, but by the time you enter the industry, who knows? C# or Java or Erlang or Python or GoLang might be the defacto. Just write games in whatever language you want, learn from mistakes.

Comment: Man, I feel dumb.... what was I doing at 11? Not programming...

Comment: @JTA, that's *school year 11*, presumably one year short of graduating - the OP's bio says they're 17...

Comment: @Cyclops Boy, I feel better now. Or do I? Now I realize I can't read...

Answer (score 2):

Rather than taking endless courses, you should be programming actual games - you will learn more and even half-complete prototypes will get you further in a job interview than some course credits, let alone online courses. So pick a genre you like and start developing a simple game and use Google every time you encounter a problem.

As to what language to choose, it depends wildly on several factors. Are you looking to get hired by a big game company? Are looking to go indie, developing smaller games yourself? Is the mobile market something you are interested in? AAA titles are usually C++, indies make games with just about any languages and tools, iPhone uses Objective-C and Android requires at least some Java.

You should also take a look at the Related-column on the right. Lot's of info there.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, although studying computer science in a good collage will get you further than a few "half-complete prototypes", I'm sure. At least, it's useful knowledge.